# HOW to convert CSV to record set inside T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, csv

In my stored procedure I am passing a filter (using "WHERE Column IN" clause) as a parameter. The value of the parameter is given as CSV. What is the best method to convert this CSV in to a record set.

Example:-

> `SELECT *
>   FROM Employee
>   WHERE Name IN ('John','Joe','Jerry','James')`

and I need to pass the names as a parameter which is a CSV string like

> `"John,Joe,Jerry,James"`

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Erland Sommarskog's articles. He has in-depth information on the different ways of doing this kind of thing:

> [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html)

Answer (score 1):

Create a split string function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
(
        @String VARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Delimiter  VARCHAR(10)
)
RETURNS @RetTable TABLE(
        String varchar(MAX)
)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @i INT ,
            @j INT
    SELECT  @i = 1
    WHILE @i <= LEN(@String)
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @j = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String, @i)
        IF @j = 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT  @j = LEN(@String) + 1
        END
        INSERT  @RetTable SELECT SUBSTRING(@String, @i, @j - @i)
        SELECT  @i = @j + LEN(@Delimiter)
    END
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: The split function is mentioned in the link in first answer.

Comment: I know, but we use this, so i thought an example would help