# 'WHERE IN' in T-SQL

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Parameterizing a SQL IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause)
>   [Is it possible to use query parameters to fill the IN keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589931/is-it-possible-to-use-query-parameters-to-fill-the-in-keyword)

Hi, I'm using WHERE IN in my SQL query as the user may need to enter multiple id's to show records for , seperated by commas. I have this at the moment:

```
WHERE Consignments.ID IN(@ID)
```

Where @ID will be the list of ID's seperated by commas. Problem is it works when I the parameter has one number - if there's more than one then it returns no rows. Any ideas?

Comment: Look carefully at the value of @ID. Is it properly comma-delimited? Are the numbers passed as numbers or as strings surrounded by single quotes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use query parameters to fill the IN keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589931/is-it-possible-to-use-query-parameters-to-fill-the-in-keyword) and [HOW to convert CSV to record set inside T-SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432002/how-to-convert-csv-to-record-set-inside-t-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use dynamic sql or use a stored proc with a table varaiable as in input varaible.

Comment: +1, TVP's in SQL 2008 are the correct way to handle this

Answer (score 2):

In cannot be used in this way.  You will need to do this by creating the SQL dynamically.

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(200);
DECLARE @id VARCHAR(200);

SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Consignments.ID IN (' + @id + ')';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: +1 This is the SQL variant, you could also generate the SQL in C# and pass it as CommandText

Comment: It's not a safe solution, in addition it has a low performance

Comment: @Jani: Certainly agree about the safety, but I'm merely showing how to do it :o)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have the parameters comma separated not just passing a string of comma separated ID's.

`WHERE Consignments.ID IN(@ID1,@ID2,@ID3,...)`

Comment: But, then you'll need to know up front how many values your IN clause should contain.

Comment: Take a look @ Ardman's example to do it in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a parameter in a SQL statement, when this parameter has to be used in an IN clause.

The reason is simple, you have to define that parameter as a string when it contains multiple values since 1, 5, 6 is not a valid number (assuming that ID is a numeric field).

Therefore, you'll have to use string concatenation in order to make this work.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613273/sql-use-comma-separated-values-with-in-clause/4613327#4613327) was a similar topic, a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

It should be either a comma separated list of values or IDs selected in a query:

`WHERE Consignments.ID IN('1','2')`
OR
`WHERE Consignments.ID IN(SELECT ID FROM <Table | View>)`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass literal comma-separated values as a parameter to be used with `IN` because `IN` will resolve the variable as a set (of one item, a string) rather than creating a set from your literal.

If you want to do it this way, you need to store your entire statements as a string, then use `EXEC` to run it... this will make your query non-sargable though and vulnerable to injection.

If you have SQL 2008, you should be using the TVP instead. You will actually pass in a table set of your values.