# T-SQL WHERE IN clause: one parameter containing multiple INT values will return type conversion error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

I have a SP which looks up a product (only one) by its productid just like this (it's a very simplified version of the query)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MYSP]
@productid int
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    select * from products where productid = @productid
END

EXEC MYSP 10
```

In some special cases I need to provide two or more **productid** but I am NOT allowed to pass more than ONE parameter to the SP so I tried to change the parameter from INT to VARCHAR and do:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MYSP]
@productid varchar(10)
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    select * from products where productid IN (@productid)
END

EXEC MYSP '10,20,30'
```

However it will return me a conversion error because the productid column in the table is INT.

There is a workaround for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a table valued parameter (pass a populated table type as a parameter) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: `productid IN (@productid)` would be equivlent to `productid = @productid`, which for your parameter would be `productid = '10,20,30'`; and that is clearly *not* a valid `int`. Scalar values act like scalar values; SQL isn't a script language where a parameter can be used to replace keywords or objects.

Comment: I would suggest against that dupe candidate, @PeterB. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4740486/2029983) is wide open to injection, and the accepted answer is basically a comment.

Comment: I found a way of doing it by stripping the string into a table and performing the WHERE IN check against the table. Thanks for helping!