# Azure database - run azure stored procedure from Logic App with parameter

Tags: sql, database, azure, stored-procedures, azure-logic-apps

I have created an azure stored procedure to update a column in an azure database table. It takes row IDs in a VARCHAR parameter.

> SET ANSI_NULLS ON
>   GO
>   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
>   GO
>   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateLastProcessedSugarContacts]
>     @ContactIds VARCHAR(8000)
>   AS
>   BEGIN
>      UPDATE Contact SET LastProcessedSugar=GETDATE() WHERE ID IN (@ContactIds)
>   END
>
> GO

When I call this procedure from a logic app that sends comma separated string in the parameter, it doesn't update the rows because I believe that it adds single quotes before and after the input, and ID column is an INTEGER. Is there a way to compare ID column in a stored procedure with IN operator? My input will be like 186,192,193

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HOW to convert CSV to record set inside T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432002/how-to-convert-csv-to-record-set-inside-t-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on passing in a comma-delimited list, then split the value:

```
UPDATE Contact
    SET LastProcessedSugar = GETDATE()
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(@ContactIds, ','));
```